# Jquery exception in event special change

Tags: jquery, openlayers, jquery-events

We are using openlayers in our app along with jQuery and when we click on a certain marker on our map we run into an error on IE8/7 in jQuery code wherein it crashes when its trying to handle the DOM events in the following function:

```
jQuery.event.special.change = {
    filters: {
        focusout: testChange, 

        click: function( e ) {
            var elem = e.target, type = elem.type;
```

...

This occurs in Jquery 1.4.2 and the line no in the function is 2281. Does anyone have an idea what this error is. I am struggling to debug this. It works fine on Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

Just an update I had a breakpoint set within the function click mentioned above and its not hit in FFX!

e.target is an `OpenLayer.Geometry.Point` object and when I look at the object in IE it doesn't have a type property.

Also what is that comma doing there? Is that a mistake?

The call stack shows that the above function is called at:

> var ret = handleObj.handler.apply( this, arguments )    line#1936

in the function handle of jQuery.

The error thrown is Run time error-failed.

After this the execution continues but there are many other errors reported on the page.

Please tell me if I can provide you more information, but I have no idea what is going wrong here.

Can you think of some reason why this is occurring on IE only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well we added a hack in our jquery code that continues execution at that part if the browser is not msie. some weirdass shit yet to get to the bottom of this. but the fix was necessary

Answer (score 0):

it seems that it's related to [this](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/5967) bug, have you tried updating your jQuery the latest release?

Comment: checked the 1.4.2 code for the fix mentioned and it does have it. So I am thinking its not related since we are using 1.4.2

Comment: Are you sure? checking both versions it seems that [1.4.2](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js) / [1.4.4](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js) doesn't have it. Mind of upgrading/clearing cache just to check?

Comment: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js this is where I checked and I pull my script from the CDN.

I searched for the changes as seen here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/43b3ed086dd850388c72ea1cabb557125dfe095a

Comment: Same thing, the `jQuery.event.special.change` is changed in newer versions, it may not be the problem..but just CHECK a newer version and CONFIRM if the problem still persists or not.

Comment: No did not help. same problem

Comment: Hmm, can you share the page or a test page that has the same issue to debug?

Comment: any other bug that u can think of??

Comment: The thing with IE, is that it could be anything not necessarily the line it's reporting, it could be an object declaration that is not supported on IE...etc this is why a full test page is helpful